# Xcode 9 Crashing while setting a Texture in SKScene in Spritekit

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, xcode9, sktexture

I am building a game in Spritekit with Xcode currently. After updating to Xcode 9 I've found that every time I set a texture through the .sks file, Xcode crashes instantly. I've restarted my computer, updated the app, reloaded the textures and nothing changed. I have the 2017 Macbook Prof 13" w/ touch bar. Here are the diagnostics:

```
Process:               Xcode [577]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.0.1 (13249)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13249000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       823984564
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [577]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-10-22 17:30:06.029 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        0537A8C3-9FB2-836A-088B-E5D2B7FEB3EB


Time Awake Since Boot: 100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: SKCRenderer_resource_queue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000012ceef7b8
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Bus error: 10
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x12ceef7b8:
    MALLOC_LARGE           000000012ceaf000-000000012ceef000 [  256K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> mapped file            000000012ceef000-000000012cf22000 [  204K] r--/rw- SM=COW  
    MALLOC_LARGE           000000012cf31000-000000012cf71000 [  256K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
Sending userDidChangeValue: to <SKInspectorTextureProperty: 0x7fadb2219440> from <NSComboBox: 0x7fadb221ad80>
ProductBuildVersion: 9A1004
Performing @selector(userDidChangeValue:) from sender NSComboBox 0x7fadb221ad80
```

Comment: You need to delete and rebuild your SKS file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the crashing problem.

The problem is with your @2x and @3x images. With those present in your Assets.xcassets folder - the SKS node will crash XCODE.

1. Add ONLY the 1x image to your Assets.xcassets folder.
2. place a Color Node onto your SKS scene.
3. select a texture
4. resize the texture.
5. add your @2x and @3x files later.

This solution works 100% each and every time.

Comment: Thank you 100 times for this ! I was stuck for months with editing workarounds on several projects because of this ... Moved assets to @1x and can edit again without crash.

Comment: In few months I recreated the new .sks file from scratch for another skin/them, it tool me too many hours for each skin. Now you save me!!!

Answer (score 2):

OHM,I found the reason
It will occurs if your image not equal ratio with current size of skspritenode on storyboard 
Good Luck!

Comment: Hmm... Both my image and size of the SpriteNode are 110x110, so a 1:1 ratio and it is still crashing.

Comment: Did you try saving it without changing the size? Just putting the image through an editor causes the image metadata to change, and Xcode seems to be sensitive to image metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Strip the metadata from the image before setting it as texture.

For example, using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip):

```
convert oldImage.png -strip newImage.png
```

Answer (score 2):

I found cleaning the build worked once and prior to that I put the images in photoshop and exported them as PNG's and then put them in the assets folder and that seemed to work for a while.  But since Mojave and the latest Xcode update, that doesn't seem to work anymore.  I've already submitted 3 crash reports to Apple and it's taking me nearly an hour to get 2 sprites with the right textures on the screen. Don't mean to sound rude, but Apple need to stop being a bunch of oranges on this one and get is fixed ASAP!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that may or may not work, it ain't reliable but still better than not working at all. I created an empty SKS file and set all my textures in this file. I then copied and pasted the node into the preferred SKS file.

Comment: ....This is exactly what i commented on, it is not a work around.  Your SKS file became corrupted

Comment: It's not working for me, if I create an empty SKS, drag a new Sprite and set it texture, still crashes. What do you exactly did in order to make it work? @BCode

Comment: When I posted this I was able to make a new .sks file, add my sprites in that scene, and then copy them over to the scene I want them in, but now it doesn't work. My current strategy is cleaning the build ( Shift + Cmd + K) before I put a texture in and then saving right after. It works about 25% of the time and I haven't been able to find a real fix, unfortunately.

Comment: I did just what you did and it worked fine. So far so good, but when I then quit Xcode and want to work on the scene again the next day or so, I am completely unable to open the file. Its so buggy! Did you find a workaround for that too?

Comment: Nope - I haven't had that issue. Try duplicating the file. Xcode is really killing me with these bugs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great workaround on the Apple forums.

How to fix your .sks file :

- Open your .sks file outside the project (close your project and open the file directly from Finder)
- You should see red crosses instead of the Sprites, delete the Texture name information for all of them.
- Now, you should be able to reopen the file from the project.
- Finally, reenter the Texture name for all your Sprites.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with only one of my sprite textures causing the Xcode sprite editor to crash (even after removing the @2x and @3x images). It had an image DPI of 300 pixels/inch. I changed it to 72 pixels/inch which matches the other sprite textures. No more crash.

I hope this helps someone. This bug in Xcode's sprite editor has been around for quite a few versions of Xcode and is a real productivity killer. Keep submitting those bug reports to apple.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to your computer: MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017), which is also my workstation now.

I have tested the same project (simply created by the game template with an identical texture image) on the following computers with Mojave 10.14 and Xcode 10.1 installed:

Mac mini server( later 2012)
iMac, 27 (Middle 2011)
MacBook Pro, 13 (Middle 2014)
MacBook Air, 13(Middle 2014)
MacBook Pro, 15(Middle 2014)
All of the above computers work well.

One more weird thing happens when I project my MacBook Pro(13-inch, 2017) through the AirPlay, it does not crash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what worked for me was to bypass using `.xcassets` all together. I simply added a folder to my project and imported the images into the folder. After that, assigning texture in the scene editor no longer crashed Xcode