# xcode crashes when I add an image to a spritekit node

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, crash

Every time I add an image to a node xcode crashes.

I tried all suggested solutions I found.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879397/xcode-9-crashing-while-setting-a-texture-in-skscene-in-spritekit?rq=1)

And from apple forums etc. Nothing works for me.

I reported this issue to Apple in October. They said that this is known issue. But still it's not fixed.

I tried different macs. It crashes only on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018). The same project works fine on iMac.

Could please someone help me? It's really important.

Comment: If your project works in another MacOS(iMac) just fine, that means Xcode installed in MacBook Pro has some issues. What I would do is, save my projects on my iMac and completely remove Xcode from Macbook Pro(including library files) and re-install and give it a try. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I completely reinstalled (with disk formatting) MacOs and Xcode on Macbook Pro 2 times. I tried Hight Sierra and Mohave. No luck.